# Problem to acces a position in an list c++

Tags: c++, memory

I'm implementing a function to insert a set of nodes in a set of routes. This function is described as follows:

```
void Repair_ChooseARouteAndAPositionRandomly (SOLUTION &sol, vector<int> &NodesPscine, vector<int>&RoutesPscine, DATA data, int max_slot){

  while (NodesPscine.size() != 0) {

    int aux;
    int pairpos;
    int pairRoute;
    int pairNode;
    list<VEHICLE>:: iterator irouteit;
    vector<bool> RotaJaFoiSorteada = vector<bool>(sol.SetP.size(),false);

    pairpos = rand() % NodesPscine.size();
    pairNode = NodesPscine[pairpos];
    pairRoute = RoutesPscine[pairpos];

    bool sorteaDenovo = true;
    while (sorteaDenovo == true) {

      bool rotaJafoiSorteada = false;
      while (rotaJafoiSorteada == false) {
        aux = rand() % sol.SetP.size();
        if (RotaJaFoiSorteada[aux] == false) {
          irouteit = next(sol.SetP.begin(), aux);  
          rotaJafoiSorteada = true;
          RotaJaFoiSorteada[aux] = true;
        }
      }

      bool NoJaExisteNaRota = false;
      list<int>:: iterator ii;
      for (ii = irouteit->rotaVehicle.begin(); ii != irouteit->rotaVehicle.end(); ii++) {
        if (pairNode == *ii) {
          NoJaExisteNaRota = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (NoJaExisteNaRota == false) {

        double melhorDur = 0;
        list <int>::iterator melhorPos = irouteit->rotaVehicle.begin();
        double NovaDur;

        InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata (irouteit->rotaVehicle, irouteit->type, pairNode, data, melhorDur, melhorPos);

        NovaDur = irouteit->duracaoTotal + melhorDur;
        if (NovaDur <= max_slot) {

          irouteit->rotaVehicle.insert(melhorPos,pairNode);
          irouteit->duracaoTotal = NovaDur;

          int cont = 0;
          list<int>::iterator itprim = irouteit->rotaVehicle.begin();
          list<int>::iterator itseg;
          irouteit->distanceTotal = 0;
          while (cont < irouteit->rotaVehicle.size()-1) {
            itseg = next(itprim, 1);  
            irouteit->distanceTotal += data.dist[*itprim][*itseg];
            ++itprim;
            ++cont;
          }

          sorteaDenovo = false;
          NodesPscine.erase(NodesPscine.begin()+pairpos);
          RoutesPscine.erase(RoutesPscine.begin()+pairpos);


        } // if (NovaDur <= max_slot) {
      } // if (NoJaExisteNaRota == false) { 

    } // while (sorteaDenovo == true) {

  } // while (NodesPscine.size() != 0) {
}
```

I  also describe another function and some structs that may be important to identify my mistake.

```
void InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata (list<int> Rota, int vehicle, int no, DATA data, double &melhorDur, list <int>::iterator &melhorPos ) {
  list <int>:: iterator itprim = Rota.begin();
  list <int>:: iterator itseg;

  int cont = 0;
  melhorDur = 10000000000000000;

  while (cont < (Rota.size()-1)) {

    itseg = next(itprim, 1);  

    double aux = data.l[vehicle][*itprim][no] + data.l[vehicle][no][*itseg] - data.l[vehicle][*itprim][*itseg];

    if (melhorDur > aux) {
      melhorDur = aux;
      melhorPos = itseg;
    }
    ++itprim;
    ++cont;

  }

}

struct VEHICLE {
  int type;
  int idx;
  double custo;
  double distanceTotal;
  double duracaoTotal;
  list<int> rotaVehicle;
};

struct SOLUTION {

  list<VEHICLE> SetP;
};
```

Everything goes fine to insert the first pairNode randomly chosen. However, when a second pairNode is chosen, the program runs until the line just after calling the function InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata. If I put any cout inside this function, it does not appear. I think the problem is in the line "irouteit->rotaVehicle.insert(melhorPos,pairNode);", because when I comment it, the code runs until the end.

If I have, for example, these routes:

```
route 1  { 4 2 1 3 4  } 
route 2 { 3 2 4 3  }
route 3 { 4 2 1 3 4  } 
route 4 {4 1 3 4  } 
route 5 { 2 4 2  } 
route 6 { 3 2 4 3  }
```

If we have the nodes to be inserted in any of these routes as NodesPscine = {3,2}. If node 3 is randomly chosen to be inserted in route 5, it works well.
After, node 4 is chosen to be inserted in route 4. Then, the program runs until the function InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata and the error message appears:

```
*** Error in `./heuristica': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000035d0680 ***
```

I suppose the way I'm identifying the melhorPos is not okay. But I can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post all of your code, but one obvious mistake is this:

```
InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata (irouteit->rotaVehicle, // <-- This parameter
                           irouteit->type, 
                           pairNode, 
                           data, 
                           melhorDur, 
                           melhorPos);
```

Your function is declared as this:

```
void InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata (list<int> Rota, // <-- passed by value
                                int vehicle, 
                                int no, 
                                DATA data, 
                                double &melhorDur, 
                                list <int>::iterator &melhorPos )
```

Then inside the function, you do this:

```
list <int>:: iterator itprim = Rota.begin(); // <-- This is a local std::list
list <int>:: iterator itseg;
//...
itseg = next(itprim, 1);  
//...   
melhorPos = itseg;  // <-- This is now referencing a local std::list entry
```

On return, you then use the last parameter:

```
irouteit->rotaVehicle.insert(melhorPos,pairNode); // <-- Trouble
```

The problem with all of this is that the first parameter (`Rota`) is passed by value.  That means the function `InsereNaPosicaMaisBarata` is working with a temporary `std::list`.

You then set `melhorPos` to point to an entry into the temporary list.  The problem is that on return, `Rota` has been destroyed, and you now have an invalid iterator being used on the return.

The solution is to change the function to have the first parameter as a reference:

```
void InsereNaPosicaoMaisBarata (list<int>& Rota, // <-- passed by reference
                                int vehicle, 
                                int no, 
                                DATA data, 
                                double &melhorDur, 
                                list <int>::iterator &melhorPos )
```

Comment: It was exactly the problem! Thank you a lot!